# Making a clicked QListWidgetItem borderless

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I have a QListWidget subclass widget deal with mouse events, as the picture below:

[image]

Its items will show text when cursor hover on the icon, and the hover background is transparent. Selection will be automatically cleared after click, but I'm still getting a dotted line rect around clicked item when hovering:

[image]

I set the stylesheet as below:

```
self.setStyleSheet("ListLabelWidget {background: transparent;border: borderless;}\
                    ListLabelWidget::item:hover {background-color: transparent;}")
```

If I set the hover border to borderless or 0px with:

```
self.setStyleSheet("ListLabelWidget {background: transparent;border: borderless;}\
                    ListLabelWidget::item:hover {background-color: transparent;border: borderless;}")
```

The rect still show around the textfield:

[image]

What should I do to completely hide it?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Setting stylesheet is all the code I typed relative to this question, and this situation can be reproduced by simply creating a QListWidget subclass and setting its background to transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cann't find any solution with `qss` but it can be implemented with `QStyledItemDelegate`. Here is an example for C++.

First create your own Widget for items. In my example I created in designer simple widget with two `QLabel`: for icon and for text. And add simple method for data setting

```
void ItemWidget::SetData(const QIcon &icon, const QString &text)
{
    ui->iconLabel->setPixmap(icon.pixmap(QSize(16,16)));
    ui->textLabel->setText(text);
}
```

Then subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplement `paint` method

```
class ListWidgetDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ListWidgetDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        ItemWidget widget;
        widget.SetData(index.data(Qt::DecorationRole).value<QIcon>(),
                       index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
        widget.resize(option.rect.width(), option.rect.height());

        painter->drawPixmap(option.rect, QPixmap::grabWidget(&widget));
    }
};
```

Also you can reimplement `sizeHint` method if you need bigger items.

And finally set items and delegate for `QListWidget`.

```
QIcon icon(":/crown.ico");
QListWidgetItem *item1 = new QListWidgetItem(icon, "Text1", ui->listWidget);
QListWidgetItem *item2 = new QListWidgetItem(icon, "Text2", ui->listWidget);
QListWidgetItem *item3 = new QListWidgetItem(icon, "Text3", ui->listWidget);
QListWidgetItem *item4 = new QListWidgetItem("No Icon", ui->listWidget);

ListWidgetDelegate *delegate = new ListWidgetDelegate(ui->listWidget);
ui->listWidget->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

In this implementation you don't need `qss` (StyleSheet) for `QListWidget::item`

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try this out later, but for now I'm doing it the lazy way - setting focus policy to NoFocus, since I need to override mouse events anyway.